# can i "ng serve" my application residing in C:/SuperApp from a cmd window C:/OtherFolder>

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to use VS for ng deving, not VSCode. I was setting up an "External Tool" which will run "ng serve --open". The command runs, but fails because it runs on C:/users/myname/appdata/Roaming/npm/ and cant find my angular.json , which is located in D:/myProjectName/.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to start the `ng` command in the directory where your project's `package.json` file resides.